# C++ GTKMM compiling issue

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I'm having an issue where building and running my code in the IDE is working fine but when i come to compile, i'm getting an error. As far as i'm aware, the reference it's complaining about is being called because when ran in my IDE, everything works as it should. Only when it's being compiled does it throw this error.

IDE I'm using is CLion.

Any help or pointers as to why this might be happening would be appreciated!

Command i'm running to compile code:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Error is as follows:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `GTKWindow::GTKWindow()'
```

Here are my files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "GTKWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.gtkmm.tutorial.base");
    GTKWindow window;
    return app->run(window);
}
```

GTKWindow.h

```
#ifndef GTKMM_GTKWINDOW_H
#define GTKMM_GTKWINDOW_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class GTKWindow : public Gtk::Window {

    public:
        GTKWindow();

};

#endif
```

GTKWindow.cpp

```
#include "GTKWindow.h"

GTKWindow::GTKWindow() {

    set_default_size(800, 600);
    set_title("GTKMM Window");

}
```

Comment: You aren't building and linking `GTKWindow.cpp`

Comment: Well F me... I knew it would be something simple, unfortunately looking at tutorials they never say to build all files, it's always them just building main.cpp. If you make this an answer i'll accept it for you.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem wise to use the GTKMM prefix for your GTKMM_GTKWINDOW_H header guard. That could easily clash with a header guard in gtkmm, leading to a confusing compilation error.

Comment: Yeah I had that same thought last night so I changed it, thanks for pointing it out though!